# Is there a way that I can prioritize one menu button over another?

Tags: html, css

I have created a menu bar which I tried to make beautiful and align the text right but the `a` tag overlaps the previous one what I've tried is prioritize one selector over another one. with `z-index`.
So basically I want the nav bar to look like my website but I want the buttons to be clickable and not overlapping each other for the website.
If you check an early build of my website on Desktop I think you can understand my problem better due to my horrible English writing skills.

[Website](http://rakowebdev.000webhostapp.com/index.html)

and some code

```css
nav ul {
        position: inherit;
        width: auto;
        background: none;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        padding-top: 0;
    }
nav ul li {
        float: left;
        align-items: right;
    }
nav ul li a {
        color: black;
        background-color: inherit;
        padding: 1em 2em;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    nav ul li a:hover {
        background-color: inherit;
        position: absolute;
        
    }
```

```html
<ul class="ShowDesk HideDesk menull" id="nav">
                    <li id="exit" class="exit-btn HideDesk"><img src="../images/cancel-button.svg" alt="toggle menu"></li>
                    <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../pages/about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../pages/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../pages/login.html">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: On your website, find `.menuitem` in CSS and remove "width: 100%;` and I believe just doing this will solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<ul class="ShowDesk HideDesk menull" id="nav">
   <li id="exit" class="exit-btn HideDesk"><img src="../images/cancel-button.svg" alt="toggle menu"></li>
   <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="../pages/about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="../pages/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="../pages/login.html">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

by:

```
<ul class="ShowDesk HideDesk menull" id="nav">
   <li id="exit" class="exit-btn HideDesk"><img src="../images/cancel-button.svg" alt="toggle menu"></li>
   <a href="../index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
   <a href="../pages/about.html"><li>About</li></a>
   <a href="../pages/contact.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
   <a href="../pages/login.html"><li>Login</li></a>
</ul>
```

Basically what you need to do is to wrap the li tag or div tag whatsoever inside the anchor tag. By doing this the clickable buttons will automatically take the right position.

Hope you'll find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you want to make it like this:
**HTML**

```
<body>
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">Login</a>
</nav>
<div class="">
  Rest of website
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
nav{
  text-align: right;
}
nav a{
  margin: 0 2%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

I'd be happy if it's helpful.

Comment: Yes you were helpful. I eventually just needed to style it in a different container that's basically all.

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually did was put out the header section into a different container named `navbar-container` So I could style the navbar separately from the other containers. Making the width bigger without interfering with the other code.  (I dont know in anyway if this is an correct way to code.) And I styled the navbar:

```
.navbar-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.8em 1.2em;
}

/* and removing the width: 100% from here; */
}
    nav ul {
        position: inherit;
        width: auto;
        background: none;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        padding-top: 0;
    }
    nav ul li {
        float: left;
        align-items: right;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        color: black;
        background-color: inherit;
        padding: 1em 2em;
        text-align: right;
        
        margin: 0;
    }
    nav ul li a:hover {
        color: black;
        background-color: inherit;
        
    }
```